# How to get dictionary values from list of lists (any language)?

Tags: c#, python, list, dictionary

I most interested in simplicity, so would appreciate solution in any language (also interesting how it would look using LINQ). I tried to do it in Python, but failed.

From these two lists:

```
init_li1 = [[234,45,1,86,2,0],[324,6,1],[123,1111,3]]
init_li2 = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]
```

I would like to get this dictionary:

```
{"Alpha":[234,45,1,86,2,0], "Beta":[324,6,1], "Gamma":[123,1111,3]}
```

Comment: You have to pick a language.

Comment: @roryap is it such rule of this site, or just your opinion ?

Comment: @CarlH: With two languages, this question could generate very many equally-valid answers.  Limit it to just one, please.  (Python is my preferred choice ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's very easy in Python:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(init_li2, init_li1))
```

You see, the `dict` constructor can be used like this:

```
dict(('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'))
```

Well, `zip()` will generate tuples by taking corresponding elements from its arguments.  That is:

```
zip([4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4])
#-> (4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4)
```

Therefore, we take the keys from `init_li2`, and the values from `init_li1`.

Note that `zip()` returns a list in Python 2.  If you are working with large lists, that is not memory-efficient.  To improve on the memory usage, use `itertools.izip` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned LINQ, you could do set something like this in C#:

```
        var list_1 = new List<List<int>>
        {
            new List<int> { 234, 45, 1, 86, 2, 0 },
            new List<int> { 324, 6, 1 },
            new List<int> { 123, 1111, 3 }
        };

        var list_2 = new List<string>
        {
            "Alpha",
            "Beta",
            "Gamma"
        };
```

Then you could pull them into a dictionary like:

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

        list_2.ForEach(x =>
        {
            int index = list_2.IndexOf(x);
            dictionary.Add(list_2[index], list_1[index]);
        });
```

Or, in 'query style', maybe something like:

```
        var results = from key in list_2
                       let index = list_2.IndexOf(key)
                       let values = string.Join(" ", list_1[index])
                       select new { Key = key, Values = values };
```

Printing out these results with the following should give you what you're after:

```
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} : {item.Values}");
        }
```

Comment: Tanks a lot, could you add query-style LINQ expression ?

Answer (score 0):

```
init_li1 = [[234,45,1,86,2,0],[324,6,1],[123,1111,3]]
init_li2 = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]

new_dict = {}
for i in range(0, len(init_li1)):
    new_dict[init_li2[i]] = init_li1[i]

print new_dict
```